# How are the "Login" and "Register" links from Laravel's built-in authentication system added to existing pages?

Tags: laravel

I have created several pieces of my Laravel 7 application (I'm a newbie trying to learn).  I then wanted to add authentication on top of that, so I did:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

After doing so,  I have a "login" and a "register" link on the top left-corner of every page of my app.  These links are being added by some automated method and are not changing the pages (views - *.blade.php files) that I had created before adding the authentication system.

I'd like to prevent these links from being added automatically.  Then I can add my own links to my navigation bar.  The problem is I can't figure out how they're being created or added to my views.  Can someone help me?

---

NEVERMIND - I FIGURED IT OUT.

Appearently during the authentication system scaffolding my "layout.blade.php" was modified to include both the "login" and "register" links by the addition of this code just under the `<body>` tag:

```
   <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        @if (Route::has('login'))
        <div class="top-right links">
            @auth
            <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
            @else
            <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

            @if (Route::has('register'))
            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
            @endif
            @endauth
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>
```

All I needed to do is remove that code block.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: can you ask your question more clear? I can't Understand your problem.

Comment: In a nutshell, I'd like to prevent the login and register links from the default laravel authenticate system from appearing in my pages.

Comment: do you have the <button> tags in your blades?

Comment: localhost:8000/login & register  , so you want to remove this urls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login links are created on a separate template file (`views/layouts/app.blade.php`). To remove them you need to customize this file.

This is the part where the header links are created:

```
                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
```

Comment: My app.blade.php is different.  Probably because it was added to an existing project and not a clean install.  However, a similar block of code was added to my layout.blade.php.  I found that block of code by doing a egrep search on the website's directory for one of the <div> lines.  It pointed me to my layout file.  Thanks for the answer and the time.  I must have found it at the same time you were writing your response.